# listview isnt being filled from my forloop, what have i done wrong?

Tags: android, json, listview

i have a for loop which should fill my listview with data, however its only getting the data from the first position  out of three in my json file, any help would be appreciated!

Heres my the code in question;

Edited version of code where i think the error lies

```
    imgtest = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/
    new JSONTask().execute("http://api.champion.gg/champion/ekko/");

      Champ = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Layoutmodel>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Layoutmodel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);
            List<Layoutmodel> LayoutModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            Layoutmodel layoutmodel = new Layoutmodel();
            layoutmodel.setChampionName2(finalObject.getString("key"));
            layoutmodel.setRole(finalObject.getString("role"));

            ChampionName = finalObject.getString("key");
            String role = finalObject.getString("role");
            String overallPosition = finalObject.getString("overallPosition");

            JSONObject ItemArray4 = new JSONObject(overallPosition);
            String champpos = ItemArray4.getString("position");
            Log.v("d", champpos);

            String items = finalObject.getString("items");

            JSONObject ItemArray = new JSONObject(items);


            item2 = ItemArray.getString("mostGames");
            item3 = ItemArray.getString("highestWinPercent");
            JSONObject ItemArray2 = new JSONObject(item2);
            JSONObject ItemArray3 = new JSONObject(item3);
            item3 = ItemArray2.getString("items");
            item4 = ItemArray3.getString("items");


            JSONArray jsonarray2 = new JSONArray(item3);
            JSONArray jsonarray3 = new JSONArray(item4);

            JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 6);
            ItemName = finalObject2.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject3 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 5);
            ItemName2 = finalObject3.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject4 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 4);
            ItemName3 = finalObject4.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject5 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 3);
            ItemName4 = finalObject5.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject6 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 2);
            ItemName5 = finalObject6.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject7 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 1);
            ItemName6 = finalObject7.getString("name");

            //Highest win names
            JSONObject finalObject8 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 6);
            ItemNameHW = finalObject8.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject9 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 5);
            ItemName2HW = finalObject9.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject10 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 4);
            ItemName3HW = finalObject10.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject11 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 3);
            ItemName4HW = finalObject11.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject12 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 2);
            ItemName5HW = finalObject12.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject13 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 1);
            ItemName6HW = finalObject13.getString("name");


            layoutmodel.setItem1(ItemName);
            layoutmodel.setItem2(ItemName2);
            layoutmodel.setItem3(ItemName3);
            layoutmodel.setItem4(ItemName4);
            layoutmodel.setItem5(ItemName5);
            layoutmodel.setItem6(ItemName6);

            layoutmodel.setItem1HW(ItemNameHW);
            layoutmodel.setItem2HW(ItemName2HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem3HW(ItemName3HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem4HW(ItemName4HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem5HW(ItemName5HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem6HW(ItemName6HW);


            layoutmodel.setRole(role);
            layoutmodel.setChampionName2(ChampionName);
            layoutmodel.setChamppos(champpos);
            LayoutModelList.add(layoutmodel);

            return LayoutModelList;
        }
```

So this code returns from this json - http://api.champion.gg/champion/ekko/" this image [image]

Oh and if this helps heres the XML of where the listview is;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you narrow it to where you think the issue is?

Comment: @AleksG Okay if you check again i have got ridden everything which i think couldnt have caused this error!

Comment: And where are you using that populated ArrayList?

Comment: @AleksG Which arraylist?

Comment: @Ricardo is correct.

Comment: All good, the guy below found the problems, thanks for your contributions anyway!

Comment: @Kripzy that was one issue with it returning 1 object  but i suggest you take a look at my answer too i think you may have some other issues with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning your arraylist inside the forloop, therefor it will only add one object to the list. You need to place the return statement outside of the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    //Your json logic
    LayoutModelList.add(layoutmodel);
}
return LayoutModelList;
```

Comment: Thanks so much brother!

Answer (score 1):

your issues is here

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in your listview.

listviews cannot be wrap content they must be a set size or fill parent. Why do you have a listview in a scrollview? i think you should just have a listview

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, Yeah i had a brain fart and forgot you could scroll listviews! But i also did change my code to what you suggested, so thanks!